# WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally." (Driver info: chromedriver=97) using Selenium Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I installed the most up-to-date version of Chrome, then I verified that the execution_path of the webdriver.Chrome was deprecated, I put the Selenium Service lib and still I can't connect, what could be happening in the code?

```
def create_selenium_driver():

  chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
  chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
  chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
  prefs = {"download.default_directory" : "/tmp/chrome_downloads/", 'profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads': 1}
  chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
  chrome_driver = "/tmp/chromedriver/chromedriver"
  
  s = Service(chrome_driver)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=chrome_options)
```

> WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
> WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
> (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
> (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium-browser is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

Comment: What is the browser version & chrome driver version you are on ?

Comment: This version: 97.0.4692.20

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally." (Driver info: chromedriver=97)
```

...implies that the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- The up to date [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) version is *chrome=96.0.4664.45*

[image: Chrome_96_0_4664_45]

- But you are using *chromedriver=97*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=97.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/97.0.4692.20/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports Chrome version 97

So there is a clear mismatch between *chromedriver=91.0* and the *chrome=96.0.4664.45*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v96.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=96.0.4664.45/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *chrome=96.0.4664.45* (as per [chrome=96.0.4664.45 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/96.0.4664.45/notes.txt)).