# Selenium won't run without root privileges shows WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/bin/chromedriver unexpectedly exited error

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, apache2

I have a selenium script that I execute in another python program. This program will only execute when I am logged into the server using ssh as root but not executable by the www-data user because it returns with the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/bin/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

I run the script using this command:

```
os.system('python3 /var/website/webscraping.py' + str(VARIABLE))
```

Any help would be appriciated!

Comment: `www-data` is a user that has low privileges intentionally, for security reasons. You should find a different approach than running executables from your webserver.

Comment: I am running the selenium script as a python file but it does not run as www-data user.

Comment: Have you tried using `chmod +x` for the `www-data` user on the files you are working with?

Comment: The user www-data has the proper permissions to read, write, and execute the chromedriver, google-chromium, and the python script selenium is being run in

Comment: @Python123 Can you try running the driver with the www-data user without the python side of things? `/usr/bin/chromedriver --version` and see if it errors out?

Comment: I got this output Sorry, home directories outside of /home are not currently supported.
See https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/11209 for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should have been able to execute the program as ***www-data*** user. However this error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/bin/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

...implies that the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) unexpectedly exited.

---

### *Thumb rule*

> *A common cause for Chrome to crash during startup is running Chrome as **`root`** user (**`administrator`**) on Linux. While it is possible to work around this issue by passing `--no-sandbox` flag when creating your WebDriver session, such a configuration is unsupported and highly discouraged. You need to configure your environment to run Chrome as a regular user instead.*

---

There can be numerous reasons behind this error. Your code trials and the complete error stacktrace would have given us some more visibility on what's wrong happening under the hood.

However, a couple of remedial steps are as follows:

- Ensure that *Chrome* is updated to  current *chrome=96.0.4664.45* (as per [chrome=96.0.4664.45 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/96.0.4664.45/notes.txt)).
- Ensure that *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v96.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=96.0.4664.45/) level.
- Ensure that you have downloaded the exact format of the *ChromeDriver* binary from the [download location](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.39/) pertaining to your underlying OS among:

  - **chromedriver_win32**: For *Windows OS*
  - **chromedriver_mac64**: For *MAC OS X*
  - **chromedriver_linux64**: For *Linux OS*
- Using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you need to pass the *absolute path* of the *ChromeDriver* binary through the argument **executable_path** and you need to mention the *path* within single quotes (i.e. `''`) seperated by a single forward slash (i.e. `\`) along with the raw switch (i.e. `r`) as follows:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver')
  driver.get(url)
  ```
- Ensure that *ChromeDriver* binary have executable permission for the **non-administrator**  user.
- Execute your *Test* as a **non-administrator**  user.
- Another potential reason for the error can be due to missing the entry **`127.0.0.1 localhost`** in **`/etc/hosts`**

  - *Windows OS* - Add `127.0.0.1 localhost` to `/etc/hosts`
  - *Mac OSX* - Ensure the following entries:

    ```
    127.0.0.1   localhost
    255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
    ::1 localhost
    fe80::1%lo0 localhost
    ```

### References

As per the discussion in [selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service geckodriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2903):

- Selenium does not require `127.0.0.1 localhost` to be explicitly set in the host file.
- However it is mandatory requirement to map *localhost* to the ***IPv4 local loopback (127.0.0.1)***
- The mechanism of this mapping does not have to be through the hosts file always.
- On *Windows OS* systems it is not mapped in the hosts file at all (resolving localhost is done by the DNS resolver).

### TL;DR

[How to reset the Hosts file back to the default](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/972034/how-to-reset-the-hosts-file-back-to-the-default)

---

### Update

As per your comment update:

> chromedriver is at version 97 and google-chrome is at version 96

Your main issue seems to be the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using a there is a clear mismatch between *chromedriver=97.0* and the *chrome=96.0.4664.45*

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v96.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=96.0.4664.45/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *chrome=96.0.4664.45* (as per [chrome=96.0.4664.45 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/96.0.4664.45/notes.txt)).

> You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally." (Driver info: chromedriver=97) using Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70068305/webdriverexception-message-unknown-error-chrome-failed-to-start-exited-abnor/70068563#70068563)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, chromedriver is at version 97 and google-chrome is at version 96. /etc/hosts has 127.0.0.1 localhost as the first entry in the file. I pass the executable path through already in my code.

Comment: @Python123 Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Still I don't think the error is caused by the software version because the program runs normally as root user.

Comment: Also how would I downgrade the software?

Comment: @Python123 _chrome=96.0.4664.45_ seems perfect, you need to download the matching _chrome=96.0.4664.45_ from the embedded link within my answer and use the absolute location of it within your code.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! This issue has been affecting me for a while! This solved my issue!

Comment: So sorry something happened and my server got deleted. How can I install the chrome browser to be at the version of the chromedriver?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like your browser version is not matching with the browser binary provided by you in your path. You can implement WebDriverManager to resolve your issue.

1. Install WebDriverManager module for python

   pip install webdriver-manager
2. Setup/initialize ChromeDriver service as below

> ```
> //selenium 3
> from selenium import webdriver
> from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
>
> driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
>
> //selenium 4
> from selenium import webdriver
> from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
> from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
>
> driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
> ```

More information below ->
https://cpsat.agiletestingalliance.org/2021/03/25/selenium-webdriver-manager-in-python/